# Spring + Java: Timestamp cannot be cast to Date? Pulling from SQL but type is Date. No Timestamp in code

Tags: java, sql, spring, date, timestamp

I'm currently using the Spring framework, though I'm not sure if this is directly the issue. I'm getting the following error:

`org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.sql.Timestamp cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:929)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:824)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:798)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)`

```
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked"})
public List getAllByFilter( String collectionPeriod,String sYear, String submission) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub SELECT_QUERY_BY_COLL_MSTR

    List<CollectionCalendar> orgs1 = new ArrayList<CollectionCalendar>();        
    List<Map<String,Object>> rows1 = null;
    String query="SELECT_QUERY_BY_COLL_MSTR";

    if("All".equalsIgnoreCase(sYear) && "All".equalsIgnoreCase(collectionPeriod)){
        query="SELECT_QUERY_BY_COLL_MSTR_SUBMISSION";
         rows1 = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(p.getProperty(query),new Object[] {submission});
    }else if(!"All".equalsIgnoreCase(sYear) && "All".equalsIgnoreCase(collectionPeriod)){
        query="SELECT_QUERY_BY_COLL_MSTR_SUBMISSION_YEAR";
         rows1 = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(p.getProperty(query),new Object[] {sYear,submission});
    }else if("All".equalsIgnoreCase(sYear) && !"All".equalsIgnoreCase(collectionPeriod)){
        query="SELECT_QUERY_BY_COLL_MSTR_SUBMISSION_COLLECTION";
         rows1 = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(p.getProperty(query),new Object[] {collectionPeriod,submission});
    }else if(!"All".equalsIgnoreCase(sYear) && !"All".equalsIgnoreCase(collectionPeriod)){      
         rows1 = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(p.getProperty(query),new Object[] {sYear,collectionPeriod,submission});
    }
    System.out.println("hellooooooooooooooooooo");
    for (Map row : rows1) {
        System.out.println("row------"+row);
        CollectionCalendar collectionCalendar = new CollectionCalendar(row.get("COLL_KEY").toString(),
                (Date)row.get("COLL_OPEN_DT"),
                (Date)row.get("COLL_CLOSE_DT"),
                (Date)row.get("COLL_AVLBL_DT"),
                row.get("COLL_ACAD_YR").toString(),
                row.get("COLL_NAME").toString(),
                row.get("COLL_DESC").toString(),
                row.get("SUBM_DESC").toString(),
                row.get("UPDATE_USER").toString());
                //(Timestamp) row.get("UPDATE_DTTM"));            
        orgs1.add(collectionCalendar); (COMMENTED THIS OUT BUT STILL GETTING ERROR)
    }
    return orgs1;
}

public CollectionCalendar(String colKey,Date opDate,Date clDate,Date avDate,String sYear,String submission,String collectionPeriod,String subDesc,String updateUser){
    setCollKey(colKey);
    setOpenDate(opDate);
    setCloseDate(clDate);
    setAvailDate(avDate);
    setsYear(sYear);
    setSubmission(submission);
    setCollectionPeriod(collectionPeriod);
    setSubDesc(subDesc);
    setUpdateUser(updateUser);
    //setUpdateTime(updateTime);
}
```

What I have is a search form that queries the DB and returns results into a table. I'm pulling data from Oracle DB table where the column type is `Date` but for some reason it's telling me that it cannot cast from a `Timestamp` value. I'm not requesting a `Timestamp` value at all.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: where are you exactly using the cast?

Comment: The error is pretty descriptive: you're sending or retrieving a `java.sql.Timestamp` when the code or method expected `java.sql.Date` (note: do not confuse with `java.util.Date`). Please post a code snippet with the problem in order to get better guidance.

Comment: I've added the code snippet as requested. I'm confused as to why it's throwing an error for a `Timestamp` when I'm requesting a `Date

Comment: Are you sure you're importing `java.util.Date` and not `java.sql.Date`?

Comment: What is the database data type defined for columns like "COLL_OPEN_DT", "COLL_CLOSE_DT" etc.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I changed the imports from java.sql.Date to java.util.Date and this fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: @CuriousMind The data type defined for the columns were `Date`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that one or all of COLL_OPEN_DT, COLL_CLOSE_DT, and COLL_AVLBL_DT is a timestamp in the database.  Luckily `java.sql.Timestamp` extends `java.util.Date`.

### Option 1

Change the date elements in the `CollectionCalendar` class to be java.util.Date

### Option 2

Create a class with a mehod that takes a java.sql.Timestamp`and returns a`java.sql.Date`

Here is a simple example:

```
class Blammy
{
  static final java.sql.Date convertTimestamp(final java.sql.Timestamp timestamp)
  {
    java.sql.Date returnValue;

    if (timestamp != null)
    {
      returnValue = new java.sql.Date(timestamp.getTime());
    }
    else
    {
      returnValue = null; // an exception might be better here.
    }

    return returnValue
  }
}
```

Then change the code above to something like this:

```
...
Blammy.convertTimestamp(row.get("COLL_OPEN_DT")),
...
```

### Option 3

Something else (that I did not think of).

Comment: Clearly laid out. Thank you for your contribution.